# How to activate/force Basic Auth on THTTPClient

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I can't find an option to activate Basic Auth on `THTTPClient`.

My main "issue" is that the first request response with a `HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized` and it triggers an auth event. I want to do it on the first "try".

Here is my code:

```
uses
  System.Net.HTTPClient, System.Net.URLClient, System.NetEncoding;

procedure DoRequest(const url, username, password, filename: string);
var
  http: THTTPClient;
  ss: TStringStream;
  base64: TBase64Encoding;
begin
  http := THTTPClient.Create;
  ss := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
  base64 := TBase64Encoding.Create(0);
  try
    // option #1 - build in credential storage
    http.CredentialsStorage.AddCredential(
      TCredentialsStorage.TCredential.Create(
        TAuthTargetType.Server, '', url, username, password
    ));
    // option #2 - custom "Authorization"
    http.CustomHeaders['Authorization'] := 'Basic ' + base64.Encode(username + ':' + password);

    http.ProxySettings.Create('127.0.0.1', 8888); // for fiddler
    http.Get(url, ss);
    ss.SaveToFile(filename);
  finally
    base64.Free;
    ss.Free;
    http.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Option #2 includes the Authorization in the first request. Option #1 does not.
[image: basic auth]

How can I do that?

Update - PreemptiveAuthentication does not exist in Seattle
[image: PreemptiveAuthentication]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi 11 and later, using `THTTPClient.CredentialsStorage` should work, you just need to set [`THTTPClient.PreemptiveAuthentication`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.PreemptiveAuthentication) to true:

> Property controls preemptive authentication. When set to True, then basic authentication will be provided before the server gives an unauthorized response.

However, `PreemptiveAuthentication` does not exist in Delphi 10.x, including Seattle, so you will have to stick with your `CustomHeaders` solution until you can upgrade to a modern Delphi version.

Comment: Is it possible that it does not exist in Seattle? It's a property of THTTPClient, isn't it?

Comment: yep, no such thing in Delphi 10 but in Delphi 11